# GAP-system: Generate a list of duplicate elements

Tags: gap-system

Maybe this question sounds stupid, but is there a function which e.g. takes the inputs `a` and `5` and outputs a list `[a,a,a,a,a]` in GAP-system, similar to `numpy.full()` in python?

I have searched extensively in the GAP manual, but to no avail.
I could write something like

```
Full := function(elem, length)
  local l, k;
  l := [];
  for k in [1..length] do
    l[k] := elem;
  od;
end;
```

but isn't there a built-in function for this???
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can use [ListWithIdenticalEntries](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap21.html#X80FDB1457FF582E7) but, depending on which objects you use, beware of [this](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap21.html#X7DD65BEA7EDB0CD7) explaining what does *identical* mean.

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know why I didn't find this method. haha :)